# Evaluate the integral as a power series $\int x^{11}\cdot\tan^{-1}(x^2)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the integral as a power series:
$\displaystyle\int x^{11}\cdot\tan^{-1}(x^2)~\mathrm dx$

We have been using Abel's theorem to do this (and the fact that the function is differentiable and integrable on it's interval of convergence in this case)
From what I can tell, an approach to this question would be to find a closed form similar to $\dfrac1{1-x}$ by taking the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$.

so let $f(x) = \int x^{11}\cdot\tan^{-1}(x^2)~\mathrm dx$
then let $t = x^2, g(t) = f^{~\prime}(x^2)$ 
then divide by $x^{11/2}$,
$\dfrac{g(t)}{t^{11/2}} = \tan^{-1}(t)$
then take the derivative of both sides so
derivative of $\displaystyle\frac{g(t)}{t^{11/2}} = \frac1{t^2+1}$

But I am stuck here relating this to $\dfrac1{1-x}$.  Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using integration by parts?

Comment: What is $t$? And did you mean to define $g$ as a derivative of $f$?

Comment: Note that the integral has a closed form in elementary functions.

Comment: @Shai Ok this would be easier. But it wouldn't help me study for my final :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that
$$\tan^{-1}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$
Use this to find a power series expansion for the integrand,
and integrate it termwise.

Comment: I tried using that but then I would have needed to differentiate 3 times to get the geometric series, and then I can't integrate 3 times.  Would someone be able to do this step by step? I will put up a bounty as soon as the 3 days are over.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}x^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+2}/(2n+1)$ so just multiply through by the $x^{11}$ and integrate.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}$.

Comment: I also tried sticking to this approach which didn't work out either.

Comment: This is a good approach, so for us to tell you where you went wrong, you will need to show us what you did.